# Spring Boot Embeded Tomcat Failed to Start

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I am building a system using Spring Boot. I am using Spring Tools Suite as the IDE, and I can build and run the program as Spring Boot App using Spring Tool Suite without any problems. However, when I build via maven via command "mvn package", and run the generated jar file under target/my-app.jar, the embeded tomcat failed to start. The error is like below:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at com.jdescript.JdeScriptApplication.main(JdeScriptApplication.java:23) [classes!/:0.0.1]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [jde-script-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [jde-script-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [jde-script-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:525) [jde-script-0.0.1.jar:0.0.1]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 21 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           ... 25 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
>           ... 27 common frames omitted

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>My App</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try to remove dependencies and try again to find out what's the reason.

Comment: Remove the `runtime` scope form the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.

Comment: Earlier log output should tell you why it failed to start

Comment: Can you update the questions with the entire error, not just the last part?

Comment: It is actually the entire error, but I have figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out. My system is to interact with a third party enterprise system, and my system depends on some JAR files from third party system. So I have the "-Dloader.path" points to the directory of the third party JAR files. One of the JAR files, j2ee.jar, conflicts with tomcat. Tomcat will start if I remove j2ee.jar file from the "-Dloader.path".

Anyway, thank you again for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

As Deinum suggested in the comments.

Your jar does not have the embedded tomcat dependency included in it, since you have provided the tomcat dependency scope as "runtime". Remove the scope declaration which should enable the "compile" scope by default. Your jar should then contain the dependencies required for starting the embedded tomcat container.

Comment: @Ameen.M spring-boot-starter-web artifact already includes embedded tomcat dependency for servlet context.

Comment: I agree that it is included in spring-boot-starter-web already. But if it is declared explicitly in the pom file, then that takes precedence over the one inside spring boot starter web. The pom snippet posted by OP had it declared explicitly. I agree that I could have said "Remove the entire declaration of tomcat dependency". Thanks for pointing it out.